# How to select more than one column value in a subquery select used in a select clause

Tags: mysql

Sample ps table col:

```
-------------------------------------------------------

id, price, start, end, priority
===========================
p1,            100,       feb1,    feb2,      1
------------------------------------------------
p1,            200,         feb3,    feb5,      2
------------------------------------------------
p2,            10,          jan1,    jan2,       1
-------------------------------------------------
p2,            20,          mar1,    mar3,      2
```

This query gives these columns as o/p: id,promo_price,special_price.

```
select p.id,
(select ps1.price from ps ps1 where p.id=ps1.id and ps1.priority=1) as promo_price,
(select ps1.price from ps ps1 where p.id=ps1.id and ps1.priority=2) as special_price
from p where p.id = p1
```

but I would also need their corresponding start and end dates as:
id,promo_price,special_price,start,end

when I add the start/end column to the subquery it throws an error:
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

is there a way to pull the date columns in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id,
  ps1.price as promo_price,
  ps2.price as special_price,
  ...other columns from ps1, ps2
from p 
left join ps ps1 on p.id=ps1.id and ps1.priority=1
left join ps ps2 on p.id=ps2.id and ps2.priority=2
where p.id = p1
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on why this answer should work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to use the inner queries as table-like structures and `join` on them:

```
SELECT p.id, promo.*, special.*
FROM   p
JOIN   (SELECT ps.* 
        FROM   ps
        WHERE  ps.priority = 1) promo ON p.id = promo.id
JOIN   (SELECT ps.*
        FROM   ps
        WHERE  ps.priority = 2) special ON p.id = special.id
WHERE  p.id = 'p1'
```

Answer (score 0):

(select id,price,'promo' as typ ,start,end from room.ps1 where priority=2)
union
(select id,price,'Special' as typ ,start,end from room.ps1 where priority=1)

This is the only way you can get the promo price,special price ,start,end as the start and end dates are not equal for both the entries.

Or else you can have

Select a.id,promo,promo_dates,special,special_dates from
(select id,price as promo ,concat(start,' to ',end) as promo_dates from room.ps1 where priority=2) as a left join
(select id,price as Special ,concat(start,' to ',end) as special_dates from room.ps1 where priority=1) as b using(id);

for getting all in one line